# Passing id without nesting routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I'm setting up the stripe checkout form and would like to be able to pass params from my order model without nesting the charges resources inside the orders resources.

In my order show view I have a link to the charges new view page:

```
<%= link_to 'Checkout', new_charge_path(:order_id => @order.id ) %>
```

In the Charges Controller:

```
def new
    @order = Order.find_by_id(:id)
end
```

This is passing the order ID to charges/new URL. 
So the URL looks like this:**/charges/new?order_id=2**

In the new method of my **ChargesController: @order = Order.find_by_id(:id)**
I'm assuming this will give me access to all of the order's model information inside my charges/new view. The problem is that if I try to set the amount to be charged to the total amount set in the order model I get an undefined method error. For example I try this in my charges new view:

```
<%= @order.total %>
```

This will raise the following error: **undefined method `total' for nil:NilClass**
If I remove that line from my view the error goes away. I'm guessing it means that the order id available in the URL is not passing any information to the controller.

Can someone please help me understand what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `params[:id]` instead of `:id`:

```
@order = Order.find_by_id(params[:id])
```

Comment: Thanks it's working now. I had to modified a few things. I'll edit the post with the updates.